# Are there Torah Moocs (Massive Online Open Courses)?

Tags: torah-study, internet, college-university-school

In the past couple years MOOCs (Massive Online Open Courses) have become more and more popular and well known.

http://www.nytimes.com/2012/11/04/education/edlife/massive-open-online-courses-are-multiplying-at-a-rapid-pace.html?pagewanted=all&_r=1&

Coursera, Udacity and Edx are the main providers. Does anyone know if these providers or another smaller provider or university offers Judaic Studies courses? The potential for teaching torah on a high level to a large audience is exciting.

Comment: I know nothing about MOOCs, but note that Judaic Studies departments in universities often teach things that are not Torah.

Comment: Does http://www.webyeshiva.org/ count?

Comment: @msh though most of it is Torah (loosely defined; I'm including things like Jewish history and Jewish philosophy)

Comment: @IsaacMoses webyeshiva is a different model. It seems to be a traditional class just offered online. Certainly a good thing and one i might take advantage of. But I dont think it is a MOOC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mooc

Comment: What are the characteristics that distinguish MOOCs from such classes as are offered by webyeshiva?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I was thinking of the parts of it that are _gilui panim batora shelo kahalacha_.

Comment: @msh nothing is perfect

Comment: @DoubleAA, let's continue this conversation in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10498383#10498383).

Comment: I really don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rutgers University](http://bildnercenter.rutgers.edu/online-studies) offers the following courses for free:

- [The Bible and History](http://bildnercenter.rutgers.edu/bible-history)
- [Israeli Political System](http://bildnercenter.rutgers.edu/israeli-political)
- [Introduction to Rabbinic Literature](http://bildnercenter.rutgers.edu/introduction-to-rabbinic-literature)
- [History of Zionism](http://bildnercenter.rutgers.edu/history-zionism)
- [Jews Under Islam](http://bildnercenter.rutgers.edu/jews-islam)
- [The Inquisition and the Jews](http://bildnercenter.rutgers.edu/inquisition-and-the-jews)

In addition, several Israeli universities offer Jewish related courses on Coursera. Such as:

- [The Fall and Rise of Jerusalem](https://www.coursera.org/course/jerusalem) - Tel Aviv University
- [Modern European Mysticism and Psychological Thought](https://www.coursera.org/course/mysticthought) - Hebrew University

A few other possibilities:

- [Introduction to the Old Testament (Hebrew Bible)](http://oyc.yale.edu/religious-studies/rlst-145#sessions) - Yale University
- [Ancient Israel](http://www.nyu.edu/academics/open-education/coursesnew/cultures-contexts-ancient-israel.html) - New York University
- [Modern Jewish History](http://history.wisc.edu/mosse/george_mosse/modern_jewish_lectures.htm) - University of Wisconsin-Madison
- [Jews and Christians throughout History](http://ocw.nd.edu/theology/jews-and-christians-throughout-history/lecture-notes/lectures) - University of Notre Dame

Of course, as msh210 pointed out, many professors in Judaic Studies do not teach Torah and it's probably worth checking out who the professors are and reading through their syllabi to make that determination. Nevertheless, here's a start.

Comment: What msh210 pointed out was that many teach things that are not Torah in addition to Torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I understand, what I meant is that these courses might not reflect traditional, halakhic Judaism (e.g., teaching a course on Torah that relies on documentary hypothesis).

Comment: Most of the courses listed here are about the history of Jews and are not Torah courses at all.

Comment: @Aryeh what I meant was even such a course would contain some things that are problematic and some things that are valuable. whether or not it is worth going and listening only for the good stuff is a different question

Comment: @Aryeh People will not know there is a valid other way of learning bible if Yeshiva University,Bar Ilan or some other university with professors who are Talmidei Chachamim don't offer courses also.

Comment: @MichaelHorwitz You can find thousands of lectures on all aspects of Judaism from Yeshiva University's http://www.yutorah.org/index.cfm

Comment: @aryeh There is a huge difference between an organized course and stand alone lectures.